# Regex in Python for substring

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all 3 character substrings in a string using RegEx.

Here's what I've implemented:

```
text = "ffjsnfksjnffnjfeff"

print(re.findall("(?=...",text))
```

However, the output is a list of empty strings:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Ideally, what I want is:

```
['ffj', 'fjs', 'jsn', 'snf', 'nfk', 'fks', ... , 'fef', 'eff']
```

I figured . will match with any character so ... will match with any three characters, and the lookahead assertion will manage the overlap aspect.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to do this using regex specifically? This would be a lot easier using string slicing

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDAXQ3VO4tU0MC7PxLCbyI4iFAIsxnr2@V59xFvVm8a6ljbmFqbaog1twiHrsOTPxtrJ7/SdCCwGpK66eFNCEAJCI2Q8): `re.findall('(?=(.{3}))','ffjsnfksjnffnjfeff')` - just capture the contents of the lookahead.

Comment: why not `print([text[x-3:x] for x in range(len(text)+1) if x > 2])` ?

Comment: @ctwheels thanks, forgot to paste the +1 for the range. fixed

Comment: thanks @ggorlen, yeah I guess this is a duplicate.